# Placeholder text padding

Tags: css, padding

Is it possible to have individual padding or margins on placeholder text or am I forced into

```
text-align:center;
```

example http://www.bootply.com/ei0b9daoqq

Comment: Are you trying to align the placeholder to the center using padding ?

Comment: @Akshay
Yes. Is that something that is possible with multiple form elements?

Comment: Do you want specific padding for each input or a common padding?

Comment: @Akshay  

Specific for each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give another class name to each of your input and give a specific padding to each of them [Link](http://www.bootply.com/WbFk4ur4yp)

#### HTML

```
<input class="form one" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="First and Last name"></div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-3">
<input class="form second" type="email" name="Phone" placeholder="@gmail.com">
 </div>
 <div class="row col-md-3 ">
<input id="email" class="form third" type="tel" name="Zip" placeholder="Zip ">
 </div>
```

#### CSS

```
.form {
background-color: #666;
color:#fff;
}

.second::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color:white;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding-left:40px;
 }
.third::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color:white;
letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 padding-left:50px;
}

.one::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color:white;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding-left:80px
}
   .form::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 color:white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

 }
```